# JS play button for HTML5 does not work on iOS mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-video

I'm trying to get an HTML5 video to play on mobile iOS. Desktop & android work fine.
Clicking the button enters fullscreen mode and plays the video.
I'm seeing reports that some cannot click the button at all though the video thumbnail is loading. The breakdown is currently:

- iOS 16.0.2 not working
- iOS 15.2.1 works using safari but not firefox or chrome

HTML snippet
`

```
<div class="video-player">
        <video loop="true" width="400px" preload="auto" playsinline="true" controls="true">
          <source src="media/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          <source src="media/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
          <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video. Here is
            a <a href="media/video.mp4">link to the video</a> instead </p>
        </video>
        <button><img src="img/play_video.svg"></button>
      </div>
```

Script in Use

```
/* Get elements */
var brimmingVideo = document.querySelector('#brimming .video-player video');
var brimmingFullscreen = document.querySelector('#brimming .video-player button');
var brimmingIcon = document.querySelector('#brimming .video-player button img');

/* Build out functions */
// toggle play/pause
function brimmingtogglePlay() {
  var method = brimmingVideo.paused ? 'play' : 'pause';
  brimmingVideo[method]();
}

// Create fullscreen video button
function brimmingtoggleFullscreen() {
  if (brimmingVideo.requestFullScreen) {
    brimmingVideo.requestFullScreen();
    brimmingtogglePlay();
  } else if (brimmingVideo.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    brimmingVideo.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    brimmingtogglePlay();
  } else if (brimmingVideo.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    brimmingVideo.mozRequestFullScreen();
    brimmingtogglePlay();
  } else if (vid.webkitEnterFullscreen) {
    vid.webkitEnterFullscreen();
 }
  ;
  brimmingVideo.controls = true;
  brimmingVideo.muted = false;
  brimmingIcon.className = "hide";
}

// what happens when you exit fullscreen
function brimmingexitHandler() {
  if (document.webkitIsFullScreen === false) {
    brimmingtogglePlay();
    brimmingVideo.muted = true;
    brimmingVideo.controls = false;
  } else if (document.mozFullScreen === false) {
    brimmingtogglePlay();
    brimmingVideo.muted = true;
    brimmingVideo.controls = false;
  } else if (document.msFullscreenElement === false) {
    brimmingtogglePlay();
    brimmingVideo.muted = true;
    brimmingVideo.controls = false;
  }
}

/* Hook up event listeners */
// Click events
brimmingFullscreen.addEventListener('click', brimmingtoggleFullscreen);

// Exit fullscreen event
brimmingVideo.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', brimmingexitHandler, false);
brimmingVideo.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', brimmingexitHandler, false);
brimmingVideo.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', brimmingexitHandler, false);
brimmingVideo.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', brimmingexitHandler, false);
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Three things are causing this problem:

1. At javascript, removing return false; of the event listener.
2. At the stylesheet, the element which calls the action must have the property cursor: pointer;. Probably Apple put this requirement in these calls for best feedback on a user interface.
3. Again at the stylesheet, we can't set display: none; for hidden input because some browsers don't accept clicks on elements that aren't displayed. (This doesn't apply for you)

Also, the general rule is to "grab" DOM elements only after DOM was loaded!